# How to get Wavefront .obj file with 3 faces (traingle)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d

I have a .obj file with 4 faces (polygon)

How can i convert the 4 faces polygon to 3 faces triangles? 
is there any script available to do so?

Is there any Engine which loads 4 faces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use blender to convert wavefront .obj file with quads to triangles.

1. Import wavefront .obj file in Blender and change the mode to Edit Mode.
2. Now select all the meshes.
3. Go to Mesh -> Face menu options and select convert Quads to triangles
4. Export the current model again to wavefront .obj file

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html

Answer (score 0):

Assume n-gons are coplanar and [triangulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) them.