# How to use Fortran to read the face information from a *.obj file

Tags: io, fortran, special-characters, gfortran, cad

#### Problem

How can modern Fortran navigate a file with double forward slashes between entries, as in the *.obj format? The goal is to extract the vertex index (first entry) and ignore the vertex normal index (second entry).

#### Example

For example, for this snippet,

```
f 297//763 298//763 296//763
f 296//764 298//764 295//764
f 384//765 385//765 382//765
f 384//766 382//766 383//766
```

the goal is to create an array like this:

```
face ( 1 ) = [297, 298, 296]
face ( 2 ) = [296, 298, 295]
face ( 3 ) = [384, 385, 382]
face ( 4 ) = [384, 382, 383]
```

Extra points for an answer which would adopt to a richer format like

```
f a//b//c  d//e//f g//h//i j//k//l
```

#### Other posts

The answer for [[How to get Wavefront .obj file with 3 faces (traingle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257272/how-to-get-wavefront-obj-file-with-3-faces-traingle]) points to a deleted blog. This post [[How to read numeric data from a string in FORTRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761661/how-to-read-numeric-data-from-a-string-in-fortran]) was not relevant.

#### References

Three references on the *.obj format:
[Object Files (.obj)](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/), [B1. Object Files (.obj)](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~boulos/cs3505/obj_spec.pdf), [Wavefront .obj file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  What have you tried?

Comment: Step 1 - use `sed` (or another similar tool) to preprocess the file to replace `//` with spaces.  Step 2 - use Fortran's *list-directed* input capabilities to read a line with one character and 6 integers (v easy).  Step 3 - slot data into the `face` array as you wish.

Comment: @evets: Not a homework problem. The task is to harvest *.obj files from CAD routines to extract surfaces for input to other analysis routines.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: Yes, sed and awk (and others will work), but the goal is to deliver a single Fortran executable. Please note the task is to take the leading terms, not all terms (3 integers vs. 6).

Comment: Well, what have your tried?  Opening the file with `access=stream` allows you to read the file a character at a time, which allows you to write a parser to do whatever you want.  Simply opening the file and reading with `write(*,'(A)')` will read an entire line.  You can then use `INDEX` to scan for `/` and peak at the next character to find `'//'`.  Fairly trivial stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, we can replace `/` by a space using  `sed` etc. We can also scan each character one by one in Fortran (see below). We then read in all integers into `vals` and select the desired part as `vals( 1:6:2 )`. A similar approach can be used for `f a//b//c  d//e//f ...` etc by changing 1:6:2 to 1:12:3 etc.

```
[test.f90]
program main
    implicit none
    character(100) buf
    integer vals(10), ios, i

    open(10, file="test.dat", status="old")
    do
        read(10, "(a)", iostat=ios) buf
        if (ios /= 0) exit

        do i = 1, len(buf)
            if (buf(i:i) == "/") buf(i:i) = " "   !! replace "/" by " "
        enddo

        read(buf(2:), *) vals( 1:6 )  !! read all items
        print *, vals( 1:6:2 )  !! select items 1, 3, 5
    enddo
    close(10)
end

[test.dat]
f 297//763 298//763 296//763
f 296//764 298//764 295//764
f 384//765 385//765 382//765
f 384//766 382//766 383//766

$ gfortran test.f90 && ./a.out
     297         298         296
     296         298         295
     384         385         382
     384         382         383
```

---

Just for fun, here is a similar code in Python, which is shorter thanks to `replace()` and `split()`. If we have some similar routines, I guess the above code may also become shorter.

```
dat = []
for line in open("test.dat").readlines():
    dat.append( line[1:] .replace("/", " ") .split() [::2] )

import numpy as np
face = np.array(dat, dtype=int)
print(face)

$ python test.py
[[297 298 296]
 [296 298 295]
 [384 385 382]
 [384 382 383]]
```

Comment: I initially used "merge" for replacing characters, but I changed it to a simple "if" because it was simpler in this case...